# Finding objective vectors

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let A and **b** be defined as follows:

A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}

**b** = \begin{bmatrix} 12 \\ 12 \\ \end{bmatrix}

a) Draw the polyhedron P(A, **b**) and write down the coordinates of all of the vertices

b) Choose one vertex *u* of P(A, **b**). Write down an objective vector **c**$^T$ such that *u* is the unique optimal solution to the linear program that maximizes **c**$^T$ over all points **x** $\in$ P(A, **b**)

c) Choose two distinct vertices *u* and *v* of P(A, **b**). Write down an objective vector **c**$^T$ such that *u* and *v* are both optimal solutions to the linear program that maximizes **c**$^T$ over all points **x** $\in$ P(A, **b**)

So I have completed the first bit already. The vertices are (0,6), (4,4), (6,0) and (0,0). Conceptually I understand what the question is asking but I don't quite know how to actually find the objective vector. I'm assuming there is some robust way to do it.

Comment: Which vertex did you choose for part b?

Comment: I choose (4,4). Not because of a particular preference but because in general, it would probably be the maximizing vertex

Comment: OK, then consider the line through $(4,4)$ that is perpendicular to the line through $(0,0)$ and $(4,4)$.

Comment: The line going through (0,0) and (4,4) is -x1 + x2 = 0 so the line perpendicular to it is x1 + x2 = 8?

Comment: Yes, so take $c^T=[1,1]$ so that $c^T x=x_1+x_2$.

Comment: For part c, if two vertices are both optimal, then so is every point on the line between them.  The equation of that line will suggest the right objective vector $c^T$.

Comment: How would one apply this to c? I'm assuming the process is similar ie. find the line going between the origin and the vertex and then find the line perpendicular to it. Also, would I be correct in assuming that the situation in b will result in the simplex algorithm cycling (if Bland's rules are not applied) - trying to see how a few different concepts fit together here.